# How to track down WP site unwanted redirect to HTTP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

We need to force HTTPS for our e-commerce site, but when we try, it goes into an
HTTPS -> HTTP -> HTTPS
loop.

A couple experienced techs reviewed our `.htaccess`, and that's not the culprit.
I checked our `wp_config.php`, and nothing there.

Where else should I be looking?
How would one hunt this down?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inside functions.php to force the http URL's to https ,

```
function fun_force_https () {

  if ( !is_ssl() ) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
    exit();
  }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'fun_force_https', 1 );
```

It will force and correctly redirect the http URL's and remove unwanted http redirects back from https.